# Power Query: Extracting value from nested lists

Tags: powerquery, m

Hello hope someone can assist me in a power query I'm having trouble with. I'm brand new to Power Query and the M language and while I do have some coding background coding is not my day job. I'm pulling data from web page and the data in one column that is a list nested in a list.
This is a clip of what I see at from query initially:

[image]

I then drill down on the list and see this for all of the rows:

[image]

I then drill down again in that list and get a this:

[image]

At this level I get at least one row but there could be many rows.

What I want is to take all of the values and combine them into one cell as a bulleted list like this:

[image]

Any assistance on how to do this would be appreciated

I've tried looking at some of the examples in other threads and only get errors when I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really provide enough detail here, but it looks like a bunch of lists within lists

you can run them through something like this to expand them all.  If the results dont look like what you want, provide more information and sample data we can reproduce

```
let  Source = <<copy whatever your source is here>>,
//Marcel Beug 2017
TableSchema = Table.Schema(Source),
ColumnNames = Table.SelectColumns(TableSchema,{"Name"}),
IsListColumn = Table.AddColumn(ColumnNames, "IsListColumn?", each List.AllTrue(List.Transform(Table.Column(Source,[Name]), each _ is list))),
NonListColumns = Table.SelectRows(IsListColumn, each ([#"IsListColumn?"] = false)),
NonListColumnNames = Table.RemoveColumns(NonListColumns,{"IsListColumn?"})[Name],
SelectNonListColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source,NonListColumnNames),
ListColumns = Table.SelectRows(IsListColumn, each ([#"IsListColumn?"] = true)),
ListColumnNames = Table.RemoveColumns(ListColumns,{"IsListColumn?"})[Name],
SelectListColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Source,ListColumnNames),
TableFromLists = Table.AddColumn(SelectListColumns, "TableFromLists", each Table.FromColumns(Record.FieldValues(_))),
ListTables = Table.SelectColumns(TableFromLists,{"TableFromLists"}),
Custom1 = Table.FromColumns({Table.ToRecords(SelectNonListColumns),Table.ToRecords(ListTables)}),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Custom1, "Column1", Table.ColumnNames(#table(List.Min({1,List.Count(NonListColumnNames)}),{})), NonListColumnNames),
#"Expanded Column2" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "Column2", {"TableFromLists"}, {"TableFromLists"}),
#"Expanded TableFromLists" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Column2", "TableFromLists", Table.ColumnNames(#table(List.Count(ListColumnNames),{})), ListColumnNames),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded TableFromLists",ColumnNames[Name])
in #"Reordered Columns"
```

**EDIT** for specific website clarification

```
let  Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/high-speed-internet-canada/en/universal-broadband-fund/selected-universal-broadband-fund-projects")),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Data", {"Location of project", "Number of Households to be served / Number of kilometers to be covered (mobile projects)", "Funding recipient", "Funding amountFootnote *"}, {"Location of project", "Number of Households to be served / Number of kilometers to be covered (mobile p", "Funding recipient", "Funding amountFootnote *"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Data", "Location of Project2", each Text.Combine([Location of project]{1},"#(lf)")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Source", "ClassName", "Id", "Location of project"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each ([Caption] <> "Document")),
#"FundingToAmount" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Funding amountFootnote *", each Number.From(Text.Select(_,{"0".."9",".","$"})), type number}})
in  #"FundingToAmount"
```

then in excel format that column as text control [x] wrap text

Comment: You are correct that that I have list within a list. I'm trying to take the text at the end and put in a new custom column. The data is on a public webpage  at this url:

https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/high-speed-internet-canada/en/universal-broadband-fund/selected-universal-broadband-fund-projects

Sorry if this is still not clear

Comment: Edited my answer at bottom. That would have been helpful it that was your initial question